# How can I check if a given member_descriptor object holds a value for a reference instance

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on an advanced interface that works mildly similar to Blender's property definitions.

what I'm doing to handle data is overwriting a member_descriptor object with a property that keeps reference of the member_descriptor's methods internally.

```
class Object(object):
    """an example"""
    __slots__ = ['item']
    def __init__(obj):
        obj.item = static_object() # stored in the descriptor and updated

def reassign():
    dscget = Object.item.__get__
    dscset = Object.item.__set__

    def setter(obj, val):
        """my problem lies here"""
        if hasattr(Object, 'item'): # this will create an infinite recursion loop
            dscget(obj,Object).update(val)
        elif val.__class__ is static_object: dscset(obj,val)
        else: print( 'FIXME: Object.item cannot be initialized with type %s'%val.__class__ )

    Object.item = property( dscget, setter )
```

so since hasattr checks the property, which checks the property, and so on, what would be a more efficient and performative way of checking if the descriptor holds the required item??

I don't want to use `try` because `except AttributeError` is super slow...
for example:

```
    def setter(obj, val):
        """the slow method"""
        try: dscget(obj,Object).update(val)
        except AttributeError: # because the descriptor holds nothing.
            if val.__class__ is static_object: dscset(obj,val)
            else: print( 'FIXME: Object.item cannot be initialized with type %s'%val.__class__ )
```

is there an alternate method, or is this poop the best I got??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some bashes to the head, and talking with a bpy dev who told me to back up and think of a better approach, I've settled on this:

```
def reassign():

    class Object(object):
        __slots__ = ['item']
        def __new__(cls):
            obj = object.__new__(cls)
            dscset(obj,static_object())
            return obj
    globals()['Object'] = Object

    dscget = Object.item.__get__
    dscset = Object.item.__set__

    def setter(obj, val): dscget(obj,Object).update(val) # leave type checking to the static object
    Object.item = property( dscget, setter )
reassign()
del reassign
# __new__.__closure__ holds the descriptor setter(s)
```

so no need for all the verification BS in the question :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the type function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Reflection#Type). For example:

```
if(type(YourObjectInstance) is YourObject)
if(type(5) is int)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to check the type of object, `.__class__` is the most performative solution I need there, `type` would only be needed if `__class__` was overridden to return another object, which even then I don't need to worry about for my case... what I'm trying to do is detect if the `member_descriptor` holds a reference or value for an instance, and `hasattr` relies on a C-sided `catch` clause I do believe, which ultimately makes it faster than `except AttributeError`.